# How to apply a CSS3 grayscale filter on an entire webpage IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to apply a CSS3 filter on an entire page, but somehow it is not working on IE11 (probably also IE10).

I went through this :

```
.grayscale {
    /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale");
    /* IE6-9 */
    filter: gray; 
    /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

but it is not applying on every item of the page itself.

### Plausibles solutions I found (but complex to integrate in the project) :

---

Create a specific SASS mixin, in order to add a specific theme to every color that applies on the website

```
@mixin theme-item($properties, $theming-properties) {
    & {
        @for $j from 1 through length($properties) {
            #{nth($properties, $j)} : nth($theming-properties, $j);
        }
    }
    .grayscale & {
        @for $j from 1 through length($properties) {
            #{nth($properties, $j)} : grayscale(nth($theming-properties, $j));
        }
    }
}
```

that is working like this for instance

```
li{
    @include theme-item(background, $white);
}
```

and results as

```
li {
    background: #fff; 
}
.grayscale li {
    background: #fff;
}
```

---

Apply jQuery function that changes every CSS property that could have an hexadecimal color and change it in grayscale

```
var hexGrayscale = function(hex) {
    var rgb = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    if(rgb) {
        rgb = {
            r: parseInt(rgb[1], 16),
            g: parseInt(rgb[2], 16),
            b: parseInt(rgb[3], 16)
        };
        var mono = parseInt((0.2125 * rgb.r) + (0.7154 * rgb.g) + (0.0721 * rgb.b), 10);
        return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (mono << 16) + (mono << 8) + mono).toString(16).slice(1);
    }
};

$('body *').each(function() {
    if($(this).css('background-color').length){
        $(this).css('background-color', hexGrayscale($(this).css('background-color')));
    }
    // ...and so on
});`
```

Quick and dirty, but less complex than changing everything in CSS(Sass)

Is there another workaround to make it without make this complex and dirty changes?

Comment: If you want every element the css selector is *{

}

Comment: You want grayscaled images as well?

Comment: While Edge browser does support some `filter` functionality, no IE version does - not even IE11. So you cannot use this feature if you want to support IE. You're going to have to do something else instead. Ref: http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Comment: @ JonasGrumann: The problem is that I don't know if every element has a 'color', 'background-color', 'border-color' property on it, and I don't want to set it because it might cause trouble 

@ MattDiMu: Yes, I want the entire content to be in grayscale for accessibility (I know that there are some libraries that does the grayscale job on images, but that's it)

@ Simba: I was able to make it work on IE9 somehow, but not on IE11...

Comment: Eventually, I just did a theme with specific colors that are "grayscaled" colors of an actual theme; didn't find something relevant about that.